# hibernate map member's field directly without setter/getter

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I have these simplified types:

```
public class DataBean extends ZZZZZ {
    public String   name;
}

public class Member extends CCCCC {
    public DataBean m_data;
}
```

I'd like to map `m_data`.`name` directly within `Member`.
I cannot use any sort of inheritance between the two (occupied already!).

This **would be ideal**:

```
<property name="m_data.name" column="name" type="string" access="field" />
```

Any idea? Is it possible with Hibernate?

Currently I'm getting this error:

> org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: field [m_data.name] not found
>   on com.example.Member

The main reason is that I'm trying to (re)use a data bean taken from an http service, and I really don't feel like rewriting all the fields, nor writing a setter/getter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `name` property is actually in the `DataBean` class. So, the exception you are getting is obvious. Because the mapping is for `Member`.

The `DataBean` is embedded in `Member` and to map the field in the embedded class you have to use the `<component>` element.

Please refer to this answer to this question here in SO: [Hibernate @embeddable annotation equivalent for XML mapping file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4753941/738746)

The answer also has a link to the page that explains what embedded objects are how to map them.

**Update:**

```
<component
        name="m_data"
        class="com.example.DemoBean"
        access="field">
    <property name="name" column="NAME" type="string" access="field" />
</component>
```

Comment: Almost exactly what I wanted - so, first, THANKS A LOT!! Secondly, can (and how) I define, in the mapping xml, `DataBean` and on `Member`, with the `<component>` element, just refer to this mapping?

Comment: Like, have two `<class>` mappings in `map.hbm.xml`: One for `DataBean` and one for `Member`. Now, in the `Member` mapping definition, in the `<component>` element, just refer to `DataBean`, INSTEAD of writing the `<property>` bunch of elements again.

Comment: not exactly... Check this: http://pastebin.com/aLuD8nsP ...... see? I want to define `DataBean`'s properties not inside `<component>`.