# setting an embedded id in a class in hibernate , using XML files

Tags: java, hibernate-mapping

I would like to know how can we set a embedded primary key without annotations , it means with the mapping shadow files of hibernate ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753941/hibernate-embeddable-annotation-equivalent-for-xml-mapping-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Hibernate verion 4.1: In the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch05.html#mapping-declaration-id) you find an example for what you want. Both XML and annotation is put there next to each other.

- **5.1.2.1.3. Multiple id properties with with a dedicated identifier type**: @IdClass and corresponding XML mapping
- **5.1.2.1.1. id as a property using a component type**: @EmbeddedId and corresponding XML mapping